# How to change THIS specific text output in django admin?

Tags: django

Hey im working in django 3.1 and i literally only need to change the name of the sections (example **ACCOUNT** on the Blue bar)

i know how to change the verbose name of the models but that does not affect the section name.

Any help? i need to have this working on spanish and it's a little messy to rename the models to the spanish word. Any solution that only affects the output text??? not the whole App name (Account is the name of the App, wich contains the 3 model class below)

[image: Screnshoot of django 3.1 admin]

Comment: account is the name of the APP sorry

Comment: @iklinac it did thank you lots